# FCS CRC Calculation

Tags: javascript, c++, crc

this is my fist question, so i apreciete your help.

im facing a project that i need make a CRC checksum, the provider send me they c++  example, however i not quite good in a low level programing, and im trying to recoding to javascript i did my best but i had a diferent result

the sample string for testing is

40401E0031303030303030330000000000000000000000001002

The c++ result are 4C4B
The JavaScript result are 49177 in hex C019

C++ Code

```
 #include <SysUtils.hpp>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <vector>
 #include <hash_map>
 #include <DateUtils.hpp>

 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 using namespace std;

 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 const WORD  FCS_START   = 0xffff;   //CRC
 const WORD  FCS_FINAL   = 0xf0b8;   //CRC
 const WORD  FCSTAB[256] = {
        0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
        0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
        0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
        0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
        0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
        0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
        0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
        0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
        0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
        0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
        0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
        0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
        0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
        0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
        0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
        0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
        0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
        0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
        0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
        0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
        0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
        0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
        0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
        0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
        0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
        0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
        0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
        0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
        0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
        0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
        0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
        0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78
 };

 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 WORD GetFcs(WORD fcs, BYTE src)
 {
    WORD xor = 0;
    WORD iresult = 0;
    xor = fcs;
    xor ^= src;
    iresult = (((fcs) >> 8) ^ FCSTAB[xor & 0x00ff]);
    return iresult;
 }
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------     --
 WORD CRC_MakeCrc(BYTE * psrc, WORD ilen)
 {
    WORD crc = 0;
    crc = FCS_START;
    while(ilen-- > 0)
    {
        crc = GetFcs(crc,*psrc++);
    }
    crc ^= FCS_START;
    return crc;
 }
```

The recode that i did in Javascript is

```
var FCS_16_TAB = new Array(
    0x0000,0x1189,0x2312,0x329B,0x4624,0x57AD,0x6536,0x74BF,0x8C48,0x9DC1,0xAF5A,0xBED3,0xCA6C,
    0xDBE5,0xE97E,0xF8F7,0x1081,0x0108,0x3393,0x221A,0x56A5,0x472C,0x75B7,0x643E,0x9CC9,0x8D40,
    0xBFDB,0xAE52,0xDAED,0xCB64,0xF9FF,0xE876,0x2102,0x308B,0x0210,0x1399,0x6726,0x76AF,0x4434,
    0x55BD,0xAD4A,0xBCC3,0x8E58,0x9FD1,0xEB6E,0xFAE7,0xC87C,0xD9F5,0x3183,0x200A,0x1291,0x0318,
    0x77A7,0x662E,0x54B5,0x453C,0xBDCB,0xAC42,0x9ED9,0x8F50,0xFBEF,0xEA66,0xD8FD,0xC974,0x4204,
    0x538D,0x6116,0x709F,0x0420,0x15A9,0x2732,0x36BB,0xCE4C,0xDFC5,0xED5E,0xFCD7,0x8868,0x99E1,
    0xAB7A,0xBAF3,0x5285,0x430C,0x7197,0x601E,0x14A1,0x0528,0x37B3,0x263A,0xDECD,0xCF44,0xFDDF,
    0xEC56,0x98E9,0x8960,0xBBFB,0xAA72,0x6306,0x728F,0x4014,0x519D,0x2522,0x34AB,0x0630,0x17B9,
    0xEF4E,0xFEC7,0xCC5C,0xDDD5,0xA96A,0xB8E3,0x8A78,0x9BF1,0x7387,0x620E,0x5095,0x411C,0x35A3,
    0x242A,0x16B1,0x0738,0xFFCF,0xEE46,0xDCDD,0xCD54,0xB9EB,0xA862,0x9AF9,0x8B70,0x8408,0x9581,
    0xA71A,0xB693,0xC22C,0xD3A5,0xE13E,0xF0B7,0x0840,0x19C9,0x2B52,0x3ADB,0x4E64,0x5FED,0x6D76,
    0x7CFF,0x9489,0x8500,0xB79B,0xA612,0xD2AD,0xC324,0xF1BF,0xE036,0x18C1,0x0948,0x3BD3,0x2A5A,
    0x5EE5,0x4F6C,0x7DF7,0x6C7E,0xA50A,0xB483,0x8618,0x9791,0xE32E,0xF2A7,0xC03C,0xD1B5,0x2942,
    0x38CB,0x0A50,0x1BD9,0x6F66,0x7EEF,0x4C74,0x5DFD,0xB58B,0xA402,0x9699,0x8710,0xF3AF,0xE226,
    0xD0BD,0xC134,0x39C3,0x284A,0x1AD1,0x0B58,0x7FE7,0x6E6E,0x5CF5,0x4D7C,0xC60C,0xD785,0xE51E,
    0xF497,0x8028,0x91A1,0xA33A,0xB2B3,0x4A44,0x5BCD,0x6956,0x78DF,0x0C60,0x1DE9,0x2F72,0x3EFB,
    0xD68D,0xC704,0xF59F,0xE416,0x90A9,0x8120,0xB3BB,0xA232,0x5AC5,0x4B4C,0x79D7,0x685E,0x1CE1,
    0x0D68,0x3FF3,0x2E7A,0xE70E,0xF687,0xC41C,0xD595,0xA12A,0xB0A3,0x8238,0x93B1,0x6B46,0x7ACF,
    0x4854,0x59DD,0x2D62,0x3CEB,0x0E70,0x1FF9,0xF78F,0xE606,0xD49D,0xC514,0xB1AB,0xA022,0x92B9,
    0x8330,0x7BC7,0x6A4E,0x58D5,0x495C,0x3DE3,0x2C6A,0x1EF1,0x0F78
);

 function fcs16(str){

    var fcs = 0xFFFF;
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        fcs = fcs16Add(fcs,str[i]);
    }

    return (fcs ^ 0xf0b8);

}

function fcs16Add(fcs,c)
{
    var xor = 0;
    var iresult = 0;
    xor = fcs;
    xor ^= c;
    iresult = (((fcs) >> 8) ^ FCS_16_TAB[xor & 0x00FF]);
    return iresult;
}
```

Comment: your c++ code never uses `FCS_FINAL` - is that a typo when typing the question here?

Comment: thanks jaromanda, was a copying mistake, but the result is correct in c++ but no for javascript

Comment: I take it that `40401E0031303030303030330000000000000000000000001002` is a hex string that is first converted to series of chars? starting with `@@` by the look of it

Comment: Thanks Mario, but until i understand, word ilen is the length, and the byte psrc is what is in iteration

Comment: interestingly - your c++ code results in `hex C019` for me

Comment: could you share me your testing implementation, maybe i miss something

Comment: thanks jaromanda, i will contact my provider, if i need more help can i ask you again? :) thanks in advance!